# Seleccionar Minimo y Máximo

Tags: laravel

Tengo un listado de productos y quiero mostrar únicamente el más caro y el más barato.

**Controlador:**

```
$precios = Precio::all();
$precioMinP = Precio::min('pcb');
$precioMaxP = Precio::max('pcb');
return view('precioluzhoy::index', ['precios' => $precios, 'precioMinP' => $precioMinP, 'precioMaxP' => $precioMaxP ]);
```

En el blade tengo un `foreach` con el listado de productos al estilo:

```
@foreach($precios as precio)
<p>Item {{$precio->nombre}} - Precio {{$precio->pcb}} - Blabla {{$precio->blabla}} </p>
@endforeach
```

Esto me funciona correcto, pero ahora necesito mostrar únicamente fuera de este foreach... el item más barato y el item más caro de la siguiente manera:

```
El producto mas barato es {{$precioMinP->nombre}} con un valor de ${{$precio->pcb}}

El producto mas Caro es {{$precioMaxP->nombre}} con un valor de ${{$precio->pcb}}
```

el error que consigo es:

> Attempt to read property "nombre" on string

Comment: En `$precioMinP` estás asignando sólo el valor mínimo, y no otra cosa, por lo que no puedes tratarlo como un objeto `$precioMinP->nombre`. Hay [muchas maneras](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#available-methods) de obtener todo el objeto que tenga ese valor mínimo, por ejemplo `$precioMinP = $precios->firstWhere('pcb', $precios->min('pcb));`.

Comment: Se entendió a la perfección de hecho agregué varias cosas mas hasta un promedio sin problema alguno! mil gracias!

Comment: Vale, si te animas, agrega una respuesta explicando cómo lo resolviste así le sirve también a alguien que tenga el mismo problema